# Occurrence of a complex type XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have this code in XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/dataset" 
            xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/dataset" >

   <!-- como poner que un tipo complejo pueda repetirse -->
   <xsd:complexType name="tDataset">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <!--  poner lo de la cursiva y todo eso -->
       <xsd:element name = "descripcion" type = "xsd:string" minOccurs = '1'/> 
       <xsd:element name = "acceso" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = 'unbounded'/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And I want to define that a complex type element can repeat between 1 and N times. That complex type that I want to repeat is the one called `tDataset` and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This element declaration,

```
<xsd:element name="e" type="tDataset" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
```

says that `e` is of complex type, `tDataset`, and may appear 1 to `N=2` times.

**Notes:**

1. If by `N` you mean an unlimited number, use `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.
2. If by `N` you mean a number dependent upon some derived
   value, you'll need XSD 1.1's assertion mechanism.
3. Neither `minOccurs` nor `maxOccurs` may occur on an element declared
   at the root level because an XML document can only have a single
   root element.

Comment: I saw a differente declaration of a complexType that could help me, but I dont know the difference between the declaration of a complexType in the code above, and this one: <xsd:element name = "tDataset" > and inside it put <xsd:complexType> blablabla </xsd:complexType>

Comment: @victor26567: Yes, both complex type declarations and element declarations can be global or local.  Please be more specific regarding your follow-up question if you'd like me to explain something more or show any particular example.  Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise, if this answers your question, please [**accept  this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215).  Thanks.